# Reducedness of pullback of hyperplanes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $S$ be a scheme, let $S\to \text{Spec}(R)$ be a morphism where $R$ is any ring, and let $f:S\to\mathbb{P}^n_R$ be a $\text{Spec}(R)$-morphism. Let $M$ be the $R$-module generated by the sections $f^*x_0,\ldots,f^*x_n\in H^0(S,f^*\mathcal{O}(1))$.

I'm looking for some kind of reference about the following question: Is the zero scheme of a "general" member of $M$ reduced? I'm open to different definitions of "general", or the imposition of conditions on my scheme $S$ or $R$. I know that if $R$ is an algebraically closed field and $S$ is sufficiently nice then it's true, but I'm looking for a more general statement. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it true that the general member will have zero set which is smooth over $R$? So, if you know that $R$ is reduced then aren't you OK?

Comment: @AlexYoucis That would be great... do you have a reference for that statement?

Comment: You will probably want to look up Bertini's theorem - this tells you that generic hyperplane sections are smooth and thus reduced. The usual form assumes $R$ is an algebraically closed field, but there are some generalizations.